# Why do I get Uncaught TypeError when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

On my web page I have linq to `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` and to `json2.js` on my web page.

When page is loaded I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: W[g].exec is not a function
    at fa.tokenize (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (point_querymain.aspx:30)
    at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2)
```

When I remove linq to this libary `json2.js` I dont get error above.

Here is my linqs that I use in my page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = '/exdata/assets/plugins/';</script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/exdata/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="/exdata/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script language="javascript" src="../Script/json2.js"></script>
```

Any idea what may cause to the error above?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information, please? Some source code of the web page where the libs are included, a demo page where we can see the error, something like that?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: it's very odd that the error stack trace does not include any code in `json2.js` - the comment in the github sums it up `There is no reason to use this file unless
fate compels you to support IE8, which is something that no one should ever 
have to do again.`

Comment: @JaromandaX what can cause the error?

Comment: absolutely no idea

Answer (score 0):

You might have linked the "json2.js" above the "jquery-2.2.3.min.js". so the execution of the above throws error.

Comment: json2.js has no jQueeeeery requirement at all

Comment: what is the absolute source path. yours src has two different links

Comment: json2 still has no jquery requirement - it was written by Douglas Crawford, I've never seen him even mention jQuery